# Error when trying to get output in txt file Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, text

Trying to pull up the contents of news details from one news website and to get the output in text file but getting error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder4\test3.php on line 8".But the contents of news what i want to extract can shown up on browser, problem is that not able to extract output the contents in text file.

Please help me out somobody what wrong in this code(on line 8)

```
1 <?php
2 include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
3 $html = file_get_html("http://www.newzx.com");
4 $content1= $html->find("div.mid-col div.news-box", 0);
5 $content2= $html->find("div.mid-col div.news-box", 1);
6 $con=$content1.$content2;
7 echo = $con;
8 file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/txt1111.txt", $con->plaintext);
9 ?>
```

Comment: `$con` is not an object, its a string, change `$con->plaintext` to just `$con`

Comment: Perhaps content1 and context2 do have a plaintext method, but they get implicitly casted to strings when concatenating them

Comment: Thank you @Dagon its working. But it contains html tags can you please tell me how to filter those html tag in text files. I am new in php.

Comment: try strip_tags()  http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Thank you @ArtisticPhonix, now i get in plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty obvious

```
$con=$content1.$content2;
```

this implies $con is a string, witch is not an object.

Comment: Thank you, now its working. one more question, can you please help me another problem. i want to extract the full content article inside of link header news from that front page of website. i posted in another question, still waiting for answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578768/how-to-pull-up-full-article-contents-inside-heading-link-using-php

Comment: you'll want to use a dom parser for this such as http://www.sitepoint.com/server-side-html-handling-using-phpquery/